# How to answer a user in Home device and send a notification to user's phone

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

Is there any way to answer a user question in the Home device and at the same time, send a notification to another device? 
For example, if the user ask for a direction, answer with the location (voice) and finish saying to the user:"I've sent you the location to your phone" and send him a map...

I know there is a way to switch conversation to another device (say, for example, one with screen) but I don't want to finish it in Home device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a straightforward way, no, but there are a few options that you have that may do what you want.

You can try to use [Assistant Notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications). Right now, notifications only appear on mobile devices, but even if/when they allow speaker notifications in the future, your user could still open it on a mobile device. You need to ask for permission to send a notification, and when they trigger the notification, an Intent in your Action will be triggered to actually show what you want to show.

You can also look into using a more standard notification channel such as [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/). This does require you to have your own app on the mobile device, and it works outside of the Assistant, but may be a good choice if it meets your needs.

Comment: I've tried Assistant Notifications, but it has severe limitations of use (10 per day/user, 1 per minute/user) and I need more than that. Thanks anyway